# Best way to convert excel file to word document using c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

I am try to Convert excel file to word document with table format using c#.net.
I am using Microsoft Office Inter op to do this. Is there any other best way to convent this.
This excel file contains images .

Comment: Hi. YOu will ahve to show some code of what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This previous question may be of help. Not sure how it will cope with the images though [How to copy a formatted cell in Excel to a table cell in Word using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672032/how-to-copy-a-formatted-cell-in-excel-to-a-table-cell-in-word-using-net)

Comment: Thanks for your replay,This approach works fine, I have done in the same way.The concern about this is performance.It takes more time for copy and past each value.I am looping each cell value of excel sheet .So I am looking for any other better approach.